# How to use media keys in Chrome with Google Play Music?

Tags: sound, google-chrome, 17.04, music, media-buttons

On Windows I can just use my keyboard's media keys to pause/resume and to skip around tracks. In Ubuntu (in my case with KDE, but it didn't work with Gnome either - 17.04) this doesn't work. Chrome does have the keyboard shortcut settings for Google Play Music, and by default they are set to Media keys, but do nothing. When attempting to reassign them I notice that the media keys aren't recognized, so I'm guessing that they either don't work or are captured at the OS level. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KDE it's possible to select a multimedia keyboard. Choosing the correct one will enable the multi media keys even for chrome and even when it's running in the background.